# Using LINQ to construct Dictionary for easily accessing registry keys for installed programs

Tags: c#, windows, linq, registry

The `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` key of the Windows registry consists of a subset of keys, one for each installed program. The key names for each program are helpfully named an apparently random string, making locating the registry key for a given program simple and easy (not!). The `DisplayName` value of the registry key contains the name of the program. I'd like to construct a dictionary (`Dictionary<string, RegistryKey>`) using LINQ that, for each registry key, maps the `DisplayName` value to the registry key itself. Any suggestions on how to do this?

In the meantime I'm going read up on [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384065%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and see if I can figure out the solution - it's the first time I've really considered using LINQ. I post my question here as I thought this might be a moderately common task and so others might benefit.

Tip: `Microsoft.Win32.Registry` is the class to use to access the Windows registry.

Comment: have you got a non-LINQ solution? tip: `Microsoft.Win32.Registry` is the class to use to access the Windows registry.

Answer (score 2):

A nice link to a LINQ example (no pun intended)

http://www.deepakkapoor.net/get-a-list-of-installed-applications-using-linq-and-c/

I would modify in your situation like this:

```
string registryKey =
    @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";

using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = 
    Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registryKey))
{
    (from a in key.GetSubKeyNames()
    let r = key.OpenSubKey(a)
    select new
    {
        DisplayName = r.GetValue("DisplayName"),
        RegistryKey = r
    })
  .Where(c => c.DisplayName!= null)
  .ToDictionary(k=>k.DisplayName, v=>v.RegistryKey);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write something on these lines:

```
string registryKey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
var dict = new Dictionary<string, RegistryKey>();

using(var key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registryKey))
{
    foreach(string subkeyName in key.GetSubKeyNames())
    {
        using(var subkey = key.OpenSubKey(subkeyName))
        {
            dict.Add(subkey.GetValue("DisplayName"), subkey);
        }
    }
}
```

or if you want to use LINQ:

```
string registryKey = 
    @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
var dict = new Dictionary<string, RegistryKey>();

  using (var key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registryKey))
  {
    var query = from a in
    key.GetSubKeyNames()
    let r = key.OpenSubKey(a)
    select new
      {
        displayName = r.GetValue("DisplayName")
        subKey = r
      };

    foreach (var item in query)
    {
       dict.Add(item.displayName, item.subKey);
    }
  }
```